# Is $\mathbb{Z}_{15}^\times \cong \mathbb{Z}_{16}^\times$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

> Consider the two multiplicative groups $\mathbb{Z}_{15}^\times$ and
>   $\mathbb{Z}_{16}^\times$. Is $\mathbb{Z}_{15}^\times \cong
>  \mathbb{Z}_{16}^\times$?

So first of all $|\mathbb{Z}_{15}^\times| = |\mathbb{Z}_{16}^\times| = 8$ since $\varphi(15) = \varphi(16)$. Furthermore, I calculated all the orders of the elements. Both groups do have the same number of elements of a certain order. So an isomorphism may be possible. What is now the next step to take? I mean I could define a bijection and check if it is indeed a homomorphism, but this is a matter of luck. Is there a nicer way of approaching this?

**Remark.** The solution should not invoke any hard theorems of abstract algebra, since it should be a solution understandable for undergraduate students in an introduction course to number theory.

Comment: The ultimate step is to give an explicit function from one to the other and prove that that function is an isomorphism.

Comment: Is classification of finitely generated abelian groups a hard theorem of abstract algebra?

Comment: Finite Abelian groups are isomorphic if and only if the multisets of the orders of their elements are the same.

Comment: You may find sections $4 - 6$ of [these notes](http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/361/lectures/lec07.pdf) helpful.

Comment: @Ennar Personally, I think it is not obvious at first sight so it may be considered hard at an undergrad level. Maybe the formulation hard theorem of abstract algebra was to weak, sorry for that.

Comment: @Quasicoherent Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both isomorphic to $A:=\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_4$. An isomorphism from $A$ to $\mathbb Z^\times_{15}$ comes from the Chinese Remainder Theorem via  $(1,0)\mapsto 11$ and $(0,1)\mapsto7$.  An isomorphism from $A$ to $\mathbb Z^\times_{16}$ is due to the fact that $\mathbb Z^\times_{2^n}\cong \{-1,+1\} \times \mathbb Z_{2^{n-2}}$ for every integer $n\geq 2$, with an explicit description for $n=4$ via $(1,0)\mapsto -1$  and $(0,1)\mapsto 3$.  As a side note, there are exactly eight possible isomorphisms in each case.  It is a good exercise to list all of them, or equivalently, to show that the group of (group) automorphisms of $A$ is isomorphic to $A$ itself.